# Three tier Architecture Using Linq in Asp.net 3.5

Tags: asp.net

I want example of three tier Architecture code or any link when i can find that code

Answer (score 1):

There is a sample multi-tier project on codeplex here:

**Multi tier architecture for Linq to Sql**
http://www.codeplex.com/MultiTierLinqToSql

and another link here:
[Building an N-Layer ASP.NET Application with LINQ, Lambdas and Stored Procedures](http://weblogs.asp.net/dwahlin/archive/2008/02/28/building-an-n-layer-asp-net-application-with-linq-lambdas-and-stored-procedures.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Some more examples:

Rick Strahl has one:http://www.west-wind.com/WebLog/posts/160237.aspx

http://aspguy.wordpress.com/2008/07/28/a-3-tier-architecture-with-linq-to-sql/

http://blogs.msdn.com/bethmassi/archive/2008/04/16/linq-to-sql-n-tier-smart-client-part-3-database-transactions.aspx

http://dotnetslackers.com/XLinq/re-53956_Creating_a_3_tier_application_using_LINQ.aspx